# dynamic import in react from @mui/icons-material not work and sometimes crashes

Tags: reactjs, dynamic-import

I am trying to use dynamic imports to import icons from the Material-UI library and display them on my web page. I want to be able to change the displayed icon based on user input. However, even when trying to import dynamically, it doesn't work. is dynamic import not the way to go. I have tried to import all from the library and that is very heavy on performance.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
function DynamicIconExample() {
  const [iconComponent, setIconComponent] = useState(null);
```

1:

```
  const Search = async (input) => {
    if (!!input) {
      const url = `@mui/icons-material/${input}`;
      await import(`${url}`)
        .then((module) => {
          setIconComponent(module.default);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
  };
```

Error 1:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@mui/icons-material/Search'
at |groupOptions: {}|namespace object:15:1
at async Search (PlaningBoard.js:13:1)
```

2:

```
  const Search2 = async (input) => {
    if (!!input) {
      const url2 = `@mui/icons-material/Search`;
      await import(`${url2}`)
        .then((module) => {
          setIconComponent(module.default);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
  };
```

Error 2:

```
  Error: Cannot find module '@mui/icons-material/Search'
    at |groupOptions: {}|namespace object:15:1
    at async Search2 (PlaningBoard.js:26:1)
```

3:

```
  const Search3 = async (input) => {
    if (!!input) {
      const url3 = `Search`;
      await import(`@mui/icons-material/${url3}`)
        .then((module) => {
          setIconComponent(module.default);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
  };
```

Error 3:

```
  FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

even when I'm not even using it
only stop crashing when commented

4:works

```
  const Search4 = async (input) => {
    if (!!input) {
      await import(`@mui/icons-material/Search`)
        .then((module) => {
          setIconComponent(module.default);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
  };
```

rest:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Search('Search');
  }, []);

  if (!iconComponent) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{React.createElement(iconComponent)}</span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DynamicIconExample;
```

Question:

1. how do I use dynamic import?
2. why is it crashing on 3rd one?
3. is the problem, mui?